# How do I find the process that is killing my CPU?

Tags: laptop, cpu, cpu-usage, intel-core-i7, hp-elitebook

My grandfather was recently throwing out an old laptop that he didn't use anymore because it was broken. It was a pretty good laptop too; an EliteBook with 8 GBs of RAM, and an i7 core, and Windows 10 Pro. So, I told him if he didn't want it, then he should give to me, since I love computers (I secretly knew that I would be able to pretty easily fix it.).

Anyways, I got around to fixing it, however, when running tests on it, I noticed that every once in a while, some process or application would start that would take up so much of my CPU, that I would hardly be able to do anything. My first instinct would be to fire up the task manager, and see what's hogging up my CPU, but by the time the process is started, the CPU is being beaten down so bad that the task manager won't even start, and I end up having to force shutdown the laptop and restart it.

So, I would like to find out what process is doing this, so I can get it off of my hard drive, but I can't because once it starts everything dies. Help?

Comment: Have you tried to use the Reset feature?

Comment: @Ramhound Like, a factory reset?

Comment: In Windows 10 there is a Reset allowing you to Reset the Windows installation but keep your personal files

Comment: Try to use process monitor with "process create" filter. With that file it shows which process is created in real time.

Comment: If it's not been used for a long while, the PC may be performing updates or scanning for malware, which use much disk I/O as well as CPU time. Check that Windows is up to date and that the files system has been recently scanned by the AV suite. Also turn off Search indexing if not needed.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Alright so I downloading process monitor, but I need a little more information on how to use the 'process create' filter, because I'm at the filter menu, and it looks kinda complicated.